# Deleting multiple records in ASP.NET MVC using jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

How can you enable multiple selection in a jqGrid, and also allow users to delete all of the selected rows using an ASP.NET MVC controller?
I have set the delete url property to my /Controller/Delete method, and this works fine if one record is selected. However, if multiple records are selected, it attempts to send a null value back to the controller where an integer id is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you have to write code for it:

```
deleteSelected: function(grid) {
    if (!grid.jqGrid) {
        if (console) {
            console.error("'grid' argument must be a jqGrid");
        }
        return;
    }
    var ids = grid.getGridParam('selarrrow');
    var count = ids.length;
    if (count == 0) return;
    if (confirm("Delete these " + count + " records?")) {
        $.post("DeleteMultiple",
            { ids: ids },
            function() { grid.trigger("reloadGrid") },
            "json");
    }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteMultiple(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // we only support this via AJAX for now.
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        if (!ids.Any())
        {
            // JsonError is an internal class which works with our Ajax error handling
            return JsonError(null, "Cannot delete, because no records selected.");
        }
        var trans = Repository.StartTransaction();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            Repository.Delete(id);
        }
        trans.Commit();
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to update this for MVC2 and jquery 1.4.2, if you want to pass array parameters to mvc2:

```
var ids = $("#grid").getGridParam('selarrrow');
var postData = { values: ids };
if (confirm("Delete these " + count + " records?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    traditional: true,
                    url: "GridDBDemoDataDeleteMultiple",
                    data: postData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function() { $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid") }
                });
            }
```

check http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14 ajax part
thx